# iOS - can stretch a UIImageView but not a UIButton?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, uibutton

Behold:

```
//UIImageView* stretchTest = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
//[self addSubview:stretchTest];


UIButton *stretchTest = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[stretchTest setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 100)];
[stretchTest setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self addSubview:stretchTest];

stretchTest.contentStretch = CGRectMake(0.5, 0.5, 0, 0);
stretchTest.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

CGRect frame = stretchTest.frame;
frame.size.height = 300;
stretchTest.frame = frame;
```

Using the UIImageView (commented out above), the image stretches appropriately - rounded corners maintain the correct radius, because only the center pixel of the image gets stretched.

Using the UIButton, the image gets stretched incorrectly. The corner radii are not maintained and it gets ugly.

Both UIImageView and UIButton are subclasses of UIView. Why does the button resize differently than the imageView?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're making assumptions about the way UIButton works. It's not implemented the same way as UIImageView. UIImageView is just a view, with no subviews, and its contents is the image. UIButton is different, and the way it works is a private implementation detail.

If you're trying to stretch an image appropriately on a button, you should use `-[UIImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:]` to get a UIImage that knows how it should be stretched. If you want to stretch just the middle pixel, you can use something like

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
image = [image stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:floorf(image.size.width/2) topCapHeight:floorf(image.size.height/2)];
```

Comment: ok... that works. I was trying to use the above because according to Apple "The use of the contentStretch property is preferred over the creation of a stretchable UIImage object when specifying the background for a view." They don't mention anything about which subclasses of UIView can or can't use the property.

Comment: A usable contentStretch on a button is desirable enough functionality that I've written (twice now!) a UIButton subclass that inserts UIImageViews into itself, and copies its background images (and the contentStretch) into them. It's not hard. The only minor gotcha is to override `LayoutSubviews` to move the imageViews to the back, so that they will appear behind the button's non-background image and title label.

Answer (score 1):

A `UIButton` has two types of images it can display -- a foreground image and a background image. The background image for a button is expected to replace the button's background texture. As such, it will stretch to fill the entire background. The button's foreground image is expected to be an icon that may or may not display alongside text; it will not stretch. It *may* shrink if the frame is smaller than the image, but it will not stretch.

A button's foreground and background image can be set in code like this:

```
// stretchy
[self setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];  

// not stretchy
[self setImage:forgroundImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

By default, the `backgroundImage` of a button will use scaleToFill to stretch the image. If you need the image to stretch using cap insets though, you should set them on the image before assigning it to the backgroundImage, like this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_image.png"];

/* This assumes your image will have a 1px column and 1px row of pixels 
   in the horizontal and vertical middle of the image that should be
   stretchable. If that's not the case (such as asymetrical buttons) 
   you need to adjust the caps */
image = [image stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:floorf(image.size.width/2)
               topCapHeight:floorf(image.size.height/2)];
[self setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```